# Run SHC encrypted bash script from PHP

Tags: php, encryption

I am trying to run an encrypted bash script from php page;

- when i run it without encryption, it runs normally
- script has two variables that is getting from php code and only one line of code

when i run the encrypted script as root without variables, it also runs ok...

Any ideas why not running encrypted...

I encrypted it using:

`shc -f <script_name>`

--
Edit:

Found out what is happening: i ran the script like this:

`$query = exec('sh /usr/lib/cgi-bin/add.sh'); echo $query;`

Instead of that, if I run it as root, like this:

`$query = exec('sudo /usr/lib/cgi-bin/add.sh'); echo $query;`

it runs OK, but still, i have one more problem:

script is now running properly, it gives output, but no php variables are passed to it;

so, my next question:

Is it possible that php can't pass a variable to an encrypted bash using:

`putenv("HOST=$host");`

If so, how can it be done?

Comment: So what *is* happening and what exactly are you doing? You're listing a number of conditions under which it works, but you're not telling us anything about what you're doing when it doesn't and what exactly the problem is.

Comment: I am passing a variable from php to bash using putenv("HOST=$host"); to forward "HOST" variable to bash. The only thing bash is doing is to remove the line containing the specific variable using sed. Once again, it works unencrypted, but when i encrypt it using the above command, it doesn't run. All test scripts run normally after I encrypt them.

Comment: How exactly are you running it? Are you capturing any output? Do you get any error messages? What's the return code?

Comment: No, script has no output and i am not getting any errors; i am running the script the same as i am running it unencrypted: $query = exec('sh /usr/lib/cgi-bin/add.sh');
echo $query;

Comment: Try to add the `&$output` and `&$return` parameters to `exec` to get some more information.

Comment: In error log, i get this¸ `Syntax error: "(" unexpected` , even if script doesn't have even one () in it; unencrypted script shows no errors